# Fluentd error="not in gzip format" despite format being set to json

Tags: fluentd

I've got fluentd ingesting logs in plaintext files where each line is a json log from s3. The logs are being ingested but then it's throwing up an error that it's not in gzip format despite  being set. This is the config

```xml
# fluentd/conf/fluent.conf

<source>
  @type s3

  aws_key_id <mykey>
  aws_sec_key <mypassword>
  s3_bucket <bucket>
  s3_region eu-central-1
  add_object_metadata true
  <format>
    @type json
  </format>
  <sqs>
    queue_name <queue>
  </sqs>
</source>

<match *.**>
  @type copy

  <store>
    @type elasticsearch
    host elasticsearch
    port 9200
    logstash_format true
    logstash_prefix gql_cloudwatch
    logstash_dateformat %Y%m%d
    include_tag_key true
    type_name access_log
    tag_key @log_name
    flush_interval 1s
  </store>

  <store>
    @type stdout
  </store>
</match>
```

This is giving errors in format

```
2023-08-21 10:41:04 +0000 [warn]: #0  error_class=Zlib::GzipFile::Error error="not in gzip format"

2023-08-21 10:41:04.732100505 +0000 fluent.warn: {"error":"#<Zlib::GzipFile::Error: not in gzip format, input=\"{\\\"@timestamp\\\": \\\"2023-08-21T09:49:10.284Z\\\", \\\"level\\\":...
```

Format is set

```xml
  <format>
    @type json
  </format>
```

So I'm a little lost

Comment: In case anyone every finds this, I found the problem. It seems that the s3-input plugin doesn't use format. I had to set `store_as` to json then it all started working

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone every finds this, I found the problem. It seems that the s3-input plugin doesn't use format. I had to set `store_as` to json then it all started working